# SAS---how to create a percentage of variable for dummy variables

Tags: sas, percentage

I'm looking for a better method to identify the percentage of a category in a dummy variable.

The dummy variable, named class1, has two categories which are pass (1) and none pass (0). I used following code to calculate the percentage of pass.

```
 proc means noprint data=HAVE;
 by date_l_;
 var class1 ;
 output out=result sum(class1)=t1;
 run;

 data WANT;
 set result;
 percentage=t1/_freq_;
 run;
```

However, this method will not be working if there are more categories. Besides, since I need to represent the percentage at the original dataset, I should use extra code to combine the WANT with the original dataset. In this case, I'd like to know whether there are easier/other way to identify the percentage of a category in a dummy variable.

Answer (score 2):

The mean of a 0/1 variable is the proportion.

```
proc means noprint data=HAVE;
   by date_l_;
   var class1;
   output out=result mean=prop n=denom sum=count;
   run;
```

Comment: What if there are three categories? e.g. 0=none pass 1=pass 2=good

Comment: Have a look at PROC FREQ. @Neal801